# Tableview, core data and JSON in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, core-data

I'm having a problem with a tableView, CoreData and JSON. And I don't know what to do anymore. I'm trying to do this:

[This is what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqUNA.png)

[This is what I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Xd8.png)
The problem is in my tableview is just showing the first object and I need to show all. The json is:

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "groups":[
      {
         "group_name":"Group 1",
         "group_id":1,
         "group_status":"FINISHED",
         "group_is_active":"YES",
         "group_students":[
            {
               "student_name":"Student 1",
               "student_id":1,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 1"
            },
            {
               "student_name":"Student 2",
               "student_id":2,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 2"
            },
            {
               "student_name":"Student 3",
               "student_id":3,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 3"
            },
            {
               "student_name":"Student 4",
               "student_id":4,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 4"
            },
            {
               "student_name":"Student 5",
               "student_id":5,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 5"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "group_name":"Group 2",
         "group_id":2,
         "group_status":"NO_MESSAGES",
         "group_is_active":"YES",
         "group_students":[
            {
               "student_name":"Student 6",
               "student_id":6,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 6"
            },
            {
               "student_name":"Student 7",
               "student_id":7,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 7"
            },
            {
               "student_name":"Student 8",
               "student_id":8,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 8"
            },
            {
               "student_name":"Student 9",
               "student_id":9,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 9"
            },
            {
               "student_name":"Student 10",
               "student_id":10,
               "student_photo":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/120x120&text=Student 10"
            }
         ]
      },
...
```

And my code on method on ViewController is this:

```
- (void)fetchGroupsFromContext {
    //Fetch and order alphabetical array
    //SERVER
    NSManagedObjectContext *contextServer = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestServer = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Server"];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptorServer = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"status"
                                                                    ascending:YES
                                                                     selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    fetchRequestServer.sortDescriptors = @[descriptorServer];
    NSError *errorServer = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjectsServer = [contextServer executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestServer
                                                                 error:&errorServer];

    Server *serverList = [fetchedObjectsServer firstObject];
    self.server = [serverList.groups allObjects];

    //GROUPS
    NSManagedObjectContext *contextGroups = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestGroups = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Groups"];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptorGroups = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"group_name"
                                                                    ascending:YES
                                                                     selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    fetchRequestGroups.sortDescriptors = @[descriptorGroups];
    NSError *errorGroups = nil;
    self.fetchedObjectsGroups = [contextGroups executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestGroups
                                                                 error:&errorGroups];

    Groups *groupList = [self.fetchedObjectsGroups firstObject];
    self.groups = [groupList.students allObjects];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.groups);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I don't know what to do. I searched to much to try to do this. I don't know if an Array is the best option to this. But I need some help.

UPDATE:
Here is what is on `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.server count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.groups count];
}
```

When I print `self.groups` it show me this:

```
(
    "<Students: 0x7f98e8cc5bc0> (entity: Students; id: 0xd000000006480004 <x-coredata://191D8908-AAA2-4527-9D05-DB582D87570D/Students/p402> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Students: 0x7f98e8cf22f0> (entity: Students; id: 0xd000000003a80004 <x-coredata://191D8908-AAA2-4527-9D05-DB582D87570D/Students/p234> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Students: 0x7f98e8cb10a0> (entity: Students; id: 0xd000000002500004 <x-coredata://191D8908-AAA2-4527-9D05-DB582D87570D/Students/p148> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Students: 0x7f98e8cf1150> (entity: Students; id: 0xd000000006880004 <x-coredata://191D8908-AAA2-4527-9D05-DB582D87570D/Students/p418> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Students: 0x7f98e8cb7410> (entity: Students; id: 0xd000000002d00004 <x-coredata://191D8908-AAA2-4527-9D05-DB582D87570D/Students/p180> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

**UPDATE:** The `viewForHeaderInSection` `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Fetch all students objects
    Groups *groupList = [self.fetchedObjectsGroups objectAtIndex:section];
    self.groups = [groupList.students allObjects];
//    NSLog(@"%@", self.groups);

    //Order array alphabetical
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"group_name"
                                                        ascending:YES
                                                         selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    self.server = [self.server sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];

    HeaderTableViewCell* headerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell"];
    Groups *groupsList = self.server[section];
    headerCell.titleHeader.text = groupsList.group_name;

    return headerCell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Order array alphabetical
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"student_name"
                                                        ascending:YES
                                                         selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    self.groups = [self.groups sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];

    CellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Students *studentsList = self.groups[indexPath.row];
    cell.titleCell.text = studentsList.student_name;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is `self.groups` when you print it out?

Comment: Also, could you show what you have for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView`?

Comment: Updated with `numberOfRowsInSection ` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView ` and `NSLog` @Mike

Comment: I haven't visually parsed everything, but I'm guessing you want to do something like `self.groups[section].count` in `numberOfRowsInSection`, or something similar? Each section contains a group object, and you want the number of rows in that section to be the number of objects in the `group_students` array, not the number of groups, right? Basically, get the *group for that section*, and then get the `group_students` from that group, and use that array as the count for the section. edit: I have a feeling I don't 100% understand how you structured this, but I think the idea likely stands.)

Comment: Actually @Mike the count it's fine but the problem is with the `self.groups` array that is not getting the others students from the others groups, it's just getting the first group of students on the JSON.

Comment: Why are you getting the first object here, rather than all of them? `Groups *groupList = [self.fetchedObjectsGroups firstObject];`

Comment: Because of section @Mike . At each section I just need only one object. I put firstObject but I don't know how to get all with this array

Comment: See my answer below - based on your description and the pictures you attached to the post, it sounds like you ***don't*** need only one object as described by your original problem statement "The problem is in my tableview is just showing the first object and I need to show all."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in our discussion, it seems your query and data structure are slightly more complicated than they need to be. I would structure it something like this:

`self.groups` would be an array of `Group` objects, and each group object has a `name` `NSString` property and a `members` `NSArray` property. All you need to do is fetch and sort the groups, and then your table view code could be something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.groups.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    Group *group = self.groups[section];
    return group.members.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    Group *group = self.groups[section];
    return group.name;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // create your cell
    GroupCell *cell = .....

    // Set this group on the cell, allowing it to update labels, etc.
    Group *group = self.groups[indexPath.row];
    cell.group = group;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It worked when I put the `Group` in `viewForHeaderInSection` because I'm using a custom section title. But now the first 3 sections are showing the first object and the others and showing normal.

Comment: You shouldn't be sorting your array in those methods, those methods are called multiple times for each cell...

Comment: Thanks for help. I removed sorting of those methods and to solve the problem of the section `Group` putting it on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with `indexPath.section` them worked fine.